# Validating multiple options with if statement

Tags: php, html, forms

I am having an issue validating that a field is empty or full. The code below will help.

The below is not the whole piece of my form, just the part you need to know. **HTML:**

```
<form action="" method="post" id="all_message">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="subject">Subject</label><br />
            <select id="No_dropdown" name="Dropown_select">
                <option value="Request for quote">Request for quote</option>
                <option value="Service inquiries">Service inquiries</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

I use this script to make a no selection on the select option above. **Javascript**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("No_dropdown").selectedIndex = -1;
</script>
```

This is not the whole PHP for it, just the part I'm having trouble with. **PHP:**

```
$subject =      $_POST['Dropown_select'];

if (empty($name) === true || empty($email) === true || empty($phone) === true || 
    !($subject === "Other" || "Service inquiries" || "Request for quote") ||   
    empty($message) === true )
```

This is the part I am having troubles with:

```
!($subject === "Other" || "Service inquiries" || "Request for quote")
```

I need that part to see if one of the 'dropdowns' is selected and if not give an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
!($subject === "Other" || $subject === "Service inquiries" || $subject === "Request for quote")
```

or

```
($subject !== "Other" && $subject !== "Service inquiries" && $subject !== "Request for quote")
```

or

```
!in_array($subject, array("Other", "Service inquiries", "Request for quote"), true);
```

Comment: I used the second method and it works as expected. Thank you!